# Why does Equilibrium produce voltage difference in Hall Effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, hall-effect

This question is bothering me ever since I studied Hall effect. Am I probably missing out a point?
To elaborate the question: I understand that Lorentz force and electric force are equal and opposite and therefore the electrons reach equilibrium. But who does the voltage is related to the equilibrium?

Please someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

by the equilibrium you have the strength of the electric field, and that multiplied by the distance gives you the voltage.I wonder why you do not look it up in one of the many description of the Halleffekt in the net, like
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect
your question " But those does the voltage is related to the equilibrium?" makes not much sense to me

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have misunderstood a point. The answer I was looking for is probably this: charge clusters create emf and therefore the upper side of conductor, which is negatively charged, has higher voltage than the lower side of the conduct. Which is responsible for the voltage difference